# How to see all elements of a two dimensional array in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm debugging my c++ code in Visual Studio 2010 and want to see the content of my array, say Q, which is 17x17. When I insert a breakpoint and try to debug, I see only the variable "Q". When I take it to the "Watch" screen and rename it to "Q,17", I see one level down.

But I want to see the other dimension,too. I can't write "Q,17,17". What is the proper command?

Thank you...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.

What you can do is put `&array[0][0]` in the memory window, and then resize it so the number of columns matches one row of `array` data.

Alternatively, you can put `array[0],17` in the watch window, and then repeat it for `array[1],17`, etc.

Not the answer you were looking for perhaps, but the watch window, while pretty powerful, just can't do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that's fairly enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the values organized in 2D in a more graphical way, you can try the [Array Visualizer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmirLiberman.ArrayVisualizer). It works fine with small multidimensional arrays.

It is a free, open source extension which can be downloaded via MarketPlace. It is designed to display arrays while debugging an application. There are versions for visual studio **2010**, 2012, 2013 and 2015, unfortunatelly it seems not to have been updated to 2017.

Comment: Array Visualizer extension can't work with C/C++. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed only works with 1D arrays. But a 2D array that has fixed size in each row (seeing the first dimension as a row as in maths) can be allocated as a 1D array as follows:

```
int ** a = new int * [n];
int * b = new int [n*n];

a[0] = &b[0];
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i-1]+n;
}
int count=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        a[i][j]= rgen.randInt(-10,10);
    }
}
```

You can then use `a` as a matrix in your code and visualise using say `b,100` if your matrix is 10 by 10.

Answer (score 0):

Put the array Q to global scope and you can see all it's elements(if it is local array you can copy to a global array and manipulate on global array):

```
int Q[17][17];
int main(){
    int x=1, y=1, z;
}
```

After debuging and the algorithm are well verified, you can use the local array as you want

Answer (score 0):

Statically allocated global memory or local variables can be viewed directly

I didn't find a way to view dynamically allocated 2-D arrays in VS2010 (only 1-D).
VS2019 can,
through

```
double ** a;
a = (double**)malloc(5 * sizeof(double*));
a[0]=(double*)malloc(10 * sizeof(double));
...
```

`(double(*)[10]) a[0],5` (add in watch window)

[image]

And this one down here will also work
`(double(**)[10])a,5`